# Email action not showing on my lightning layout

Tags: email, lightning-experience, case, action

I added my standard email action to my page layout as shown here : 
[image]

But it is not showing on my chatter component on my case lightning page :

[image]

I know that for case, lightning component action or standard action do not show up among the button sections, but it should show up among the chatter actions, because i added both the chatter action and lightning action on my layout.

Are there an email setting that control it's visibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to setup and search for Deliverability. Set Access Level to `All Email`

[image]

If it is set to `System email only`, or `No access`, it will hide the email actions on the pagelayout.